# How to stop touch event propagation in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I have a scrollview with a grid of images when I long press on an image I’d like to stop propagating the mouse events to the scrollview and just monitor the movements. With the intent to re-initialize propagation on press out. Anyone know how?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the Gesture Responder's methods: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html#responder-lifecycle . Actually even simpler way will be to take a look at the PanResponder https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html - first see the UIExplorer example to see it in operation:  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/ResponderExample.js . I am not sure though if this will handle the long-press case of yours?

Comment: I'd actually already found it and started using it. Forgot I posted the question. It makes for other problems with what I'm trying to accomplish but it's working. I use a longpress to flip scrollenabled and then use the responder lifecycle hooks to grab the events and watch for move and release.

Comment: Just add the prop `onStartShouldSetResponder={event => true}` to the <View> you want to prevent bubbling up.

Comment: @jarek the example link is broken

Answer (score 18):

Add the below to the `<View>` to catch the propagated event and stop it:

- `onStartShouldSetResponder={(event) => true}`
- `onTouchEnd={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); }}`

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.doSomething1}>
  <View
   onStartShouldSetResponder={(event) => true}
   onTouchEnd={(e) => {
     e.stopPropagation();
   }}
  >
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.doSomething2}>
        <Image ... />
      </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Perfect. This was the solution that worked for me.

Comment: The `onStartShouldSetResponder={ () => true }` alone sufficed for me

Answer (score 16):

This might be new since the previous answers, but I find you can just gobble the event using another "touchable":

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressOuter}>
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1}>
        <Text>Content</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

In this example, touching the text does not trigger `onPressOuter`

Comment: This doesn't work for if you have any <View> child element, example:
`<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressOuter}>
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1}>
        <Text>Content</Text>
        <View>
            // this.onPressOuter is called here
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</TouchableOpacity>`

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by wrap my press event with class method that set inner variable to true, then did the original logic, and after it finished, set again the inner variable to false. Then, you can wrap your container component event handler to check if inner variable set to true or false.
for example:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.doSomething1}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.doSomething2}>
        <Image ... />
    </TouchableOpacity>
</TouchableOpacity>

doSomething1() {
    this.preventDefault = true;
    doSomeLogic();
    this.preventDefault = false;
}

doSomething2() {
    if(!this.preventDefault) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This would be the simplest answer:

use this on the inner view at the point where you want the propagation to stop

```
onTouchEnd={(e) => {
   e.stopPropagation()
}}
```

Comment: This is for React Native, not React web. `stopPropogation` is a browser method.

Comment: @EhrenMurdick are you sure? it's in react native's SyntheticEvent type def right here

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1465c8f3874cdee8c325ab4a4916fda0b3e43bdb/Libraries/Types/CoreEventTypes.js#L25

Comment: @EhrenMurdick I'd recommend reading this to get a better understanding of the react event system architecture https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-exactly-does-react-handles-events-71e8b5e359f2

Comment: I stand corrected! Thank you for correcting me, this is important to know!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the `onPress` of the outer touchable was invoked first, even though I pressed the inner touchable.

What I did, was to use the `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` in the inner touchable to determine whether the user pressed the inner or outer touchable - by setting a flag in the component class, on `onPressIn` and clearing it on `onPressOut`, and then checking for that flag in the `onPress` handler of the outer touchable, bailing out if it's set.

Answer (score 1):

After well over a day in looking for answers, this worked for me.

```
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

<TouchableOpacity onPress={outside}>
  //outside code here
  <TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={inside}
    disallowInterruption={true}>
      //inner code here
  </TouchableOpacity>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Setting `disallowInterruption` to `true` will prevent bubbling of the event in React Native.
Original Source: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/784

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question years later, so providing a note for the newer react native `Pressable` in case helpful to anyone.

Originally I had a `Pressable` wrapping some content and I wanted to prevent the touch event on the content causing the pressable `onPress` to fire.

```
<Pressable onPress={() => doSomething()}>
  <View 
    onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true} 
    onTouchEnd={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
  <Content ... />
  </View>
</Pressable>
```

However, this wasn't working. The fix was to not use a `Pressable` as a wrapper, but instead a `View`. In particular note that if the inner `View` stops propagation on touch end, then the outer `View` must only respond to touch end not touch start.

```
<View onTouchEnd={() => doSomething()}>
  <View 
    onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true} 
    onTouchEnd={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
  <Content ... />
  </View>
</View>
```