# React Native prevent touch bubbling to parent elements

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, touchableopacity, touchablehighlight

If I want to prevent the onPress event on the `View` component propagating to the parent `Touchable` for the following `Sample` component, what's the best option other than wrapping the child view in a `Touchable` please?

```
export default function Sample (): Element<*> {
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
        <Text>Sample</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866671/how-to-stop-touch-event-propagation-in-react-native ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I simply put the View inside another TouchableOpacity (with activeOpacity to 1 to block any graphic effect):

```
export default function Sample (): Element<*> {
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1}>
        <View>
          <Text>Sample</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```